# Возможно ли использование оператора == в std::enable_if? <type_traits>

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Предположим есть реализация шаблона проектирования object pool.

```
template<typename T, size_t count>
class ObjectPoll {
public:
    /*...*/
private:
    size_t m_count = count;
    /*...*/
}
```

Хочется получить ошибку на этапе компиляции, если пользователь пытается создать объект `ObjectPool<Bullet, 0> bulletsPool;`
Возможно ли сделать это при помощи std::enable_if<>?
Например:

```
template<typename T, size_t count, typename = std::enable_if<count != 0>::value>
class ObjectPoll {/*...*/};
```

Или лучше сделать это при помощи `static_assert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Только раз уж вы основываете это на *типовом* параметре, то почему из `enable_if<>` вы вдруг берете `enable_if<>::value`, а не `enable_if<>::type`?

Правильно

```
template<typename T, size_t count, typename = typename std::enable_if<count != 0>::type>
```

Однако `static_assert` для этой цели действительно выглядит намного уместнее.

Comment: Я просто совсем недавно начал погружаться в возможности библиотеки <type_traits> и поэтому мне не до конца понятны все возможности ``enable_if<>``.